# WinRt convert PDF to image improve image quality

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

in a WinRt app I want to show pdf content. Therefor I convert all pdf pages to an image. But the quality is very bad. Also after zooming, it getting more bader.

How can I improve the quality!? It is possible to use a encoder? Or do I need an higher Widht/Hight value?

```
            StorageFile pdfFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

            //Load Pdf File
            pdfDocument = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(pdfFile);

            if (pdfDocument != null && pdfDocument.PageCount > 0) {

                //Get Pdf page
                for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < pdfDocument.PageCount; pageIndex++) {

                    var pdfPage = pdfDocument.GetPage((uint)pageIndex);

                    if (pdfPage != null) {
                        // next, generate a bitmap of the page
                        StorageFolder tempFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
                        StorageFile pngFile = await tempFolder.CreateFileAsync(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                        if (pngFile != null) {
                            IRandomAccessStream randomStream = await pngFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

                            PdfPageRenderOptions pdfPageRenderOptions = new PdfPageRenderOptions();
                            pdfPageRenderOptions.IsIgnoringHighContrast = false;

                            PdfPageDimensions rotation =  pdfPage.Dimensions;
                            Size pdfPageSize = pdfPage.Size;
                            if (pdfPageSize.Height > 1000) {
                                pdfPageRenderOptions.DestinationHeight = (uint)(pdfPageSize.Height * 0.85);
                            }
                            else if (pdfPageSize.Width > 1000) {
                                pdfPageRenderOptions.DestinationWidth = (uint)(pdfPageSize.Width * 1.25);
                            }

                            await pdfPage.RenderToStreamAsync(randomStream, pdfPageRenderOptions);
                            await randomStream.FlushAsync();

                            randomStream.Dispose();
                            pdfPage.Dispose();

                            PdfPagePath = pngFile.Path;
                            PdfPagesPathCollection.Add(pngFile.Path);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why are you converting them to an image? Pdf is a scalable vector format.

Comment: I need to work with it, display them in the winrt app und allow zooming. If I keep the pdf format the handling and showing directly in the app is more difficulter.

Comment: By converting it to a high resolution bitmap, your application is likely to consume an enormous amount of memory, which may cause the app to be terminated.

Comment: @GermanSniper I am experimenting with something very similar. I wanted to wrap `Image` by `ScrollViewer` and when `ViewChanged` event is raised I will call `RenderToStreamAsync` with new `DestinationWidth`, however, performance is really poor... and @WiredPrairie is right, a high resolution bitmap is consuming a lot of memory...

Comment: Have you found a better solution by now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF format allows infinite perfect zoom as it's a vector based format. When you convert the page to an image you are limited by the resolution of that conversion and zooming will show the pixels.

A solution is to render at a higher resolution and scale to the display, it will give you some zoom latitude but it will still hit a limit. On other platforms this is done by rendering just the section to view at the required zoom level but I don't think that this is possible using this `PdfDocument`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it with bitmap conversion, but the image was to large. Now I take a PDF snapshot in a higher resolution and scale it down for the normal view. And in zoom mode the quality is better because the source has an higher resolution....

Comment: @GermanSniper would you like to share your approach and solution?